# How do you disable Restlet Client logging Info level?

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

In my log I have this being displayed multiple times:

Nov 16, 2012 8:51:32 AM org.restlet.ext.net.HttpClientHelper stop
INFO: Stopping the HTTP client

I thought I fixed it when I added this code to my client:

```
HttpClientHelper httpClientHelper = new HttpClientHelper(null);
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients().clear();
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients().add(httpClientHelper);
httpClientHelper.getLogger().setLevel(Level.WARNING);
```

Apparently it worked for the start of the log but then it came up later in the log. Can someone explain to me why it started to work as expected but then it brought up that info log entry again?

Answer (score 0):

For me, setting the logService to this worked:

```
public class SilentLogService extends LogService {

  @Override
  public boolean isLoggable(Request request) {
      return false;
  }

}
```